# skupper link create with no kube config

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

Trying to establish a link from a standalone VM into a K8S running skupper. So, on purpose I used a VM with only skupper installed and no kubeconfig available, however this does not seem to work.

My thinking  is: All that skupper needs, is the token file generated from  within K8S. IMHO this file contains evething needed to connect from the outside to the skupper-router:  the Ingress address, certificates, etc. Thus, the skupper gateway on the VM can be setup totally agnostic on the k8s internals. However, trying to setup the gateway results in the following error:

```
$ skupper gateway init --type docker
invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable. Please point to an existing, valid kubeconfig file.
```

The same error is generated when trying to create the link directly

```
$ skupper link create secret.yaml
invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable. Please point to an existing, valid kubeconfig file.
```

Can you eliminate my missconception pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This discussion has moved to https://github.com/skupperproject/skupper/discussions/1142 and can be closed on SO.

Comment: Once you have found a solution to this question, please [edit] this answer to include essential details to help future readers with the same problem. Although the link provided may be useful, it [may become outdated or deleted in the future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13369/is-it-okay-to-answer-a-stack-overflow-question-with-a-link/13371#13371).